# How can I get the phpmyadmin alias to match instead of this default Apache virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.4

If do a brand new install of

- `Apache 2.4`
- `PHP`
- `Phpmyadmin`
- on `Ubuntu 14.04` server.

And I use all default "out of the box" settings I can browse to `x.x.x.x/phpmyadmin` and phpmyadmin will load - no surprises there.

I then edit the default virtual host to respond with a 404 error when a request is made to the server IP address directly.  e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "<h2>404 Not Found: Hostname not recognised</h2>This server is not configured for the requested domain"

    # Note: this has to be used or else phpmyadmin wont work - visiting http://<server IP>/phpmyadmin
    # simply results in the ErrorDocument menssage showing
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

</VirtualHost>
```

browsing to  the server: `x.x.x.x/phpmyadmin` will now cause the default virtual host with its 404 error response to run instead of phpmyadmin.
I have tried try moving the `IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf` directive lower down in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` but it isn't working. e.g.

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:¬
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf¬

# Include generic snippets of statements¬
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf¬
```

How can I get phpmyadmin and its alias directive to take precedence over apaches default virtualhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply don't, they are orthogonal.  When a request arrives, it's mapped to a virtualhost.  Aliases and thousands of other directives may be triggered to affect how modules handle the request, but they aren't substitutes for one another.

There is an obscure feature that lets you choose a separate virtual host when a specific leading path is requested. See the ServerPath directive.  This may let you pop into a new vhost, but the overall requirement is unclear.

Comment: thanks. My understanding is that one would need to take precedence over the other and therefore are not independant/unrelated . Apache must make a decision which one to use. i.e. one must "win". the problem is that when the phpmyadmin url is requested it is not being served- the default vhost is being served instead

Comment: No, the only precedence issue is Redirect vs Alias and you already see the precedence there. It's not relative to virtualhost.